# Logic constraint between different tables in SQL

Tags: sql

Consider I have three tables: `order`, `sub_order` and `product`.
The cost of an `sub_order` is built upon a complex formula which then depends on the individual costs of the products. The cost of the `order` is simply the sum of the `sub_order` costs, although this formula might change in the future.

We store the derived field `order.order_cost` for convinience.

The questions I have are:

Should business rules be applied to the database layer? If so, is there a way to force the constraint for `order_cost` using SQL? That is, `order_cost` is always the sum of `sub_order_cost`

Comment: Perhaps a view?

Comment: If the cost to recalculate the fields is too expensive, the view is not a proper choice, right? So I should use a materialized view instead, but the database is MySQL. How should I proceed then?

Comment: You can't really create a constraint that enforces that rule. What you can do, however, is to create triggers that will update the main table `order` when changes happen to the `sub_order` table. Not the same thing, but can be quite useful.

Comment: I agree that triggers are the normal way to enforce constraints across tables. I would only comment that it may make for simpler reasoning in the long run, if triggers are used to update a wholly separate `order_cost_summary` table (which consists entirely of rows generated and maintained by the database, based upon values stored in the base tables). The natural sequence is presumably to insert an order, then a sub_order, and I'm not fond of triggers that routinely go in the opposite direction and modify order after sub_order, because you're quite likely at some point to cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order cost to always be the sum of the costs from `sub_order`, then calculate the value on the fly.  There is no need to store the value, unless you have a performance reason.  Your question doesn't mention performance as a reason to duplicate the data.

If you want the order cost to be *initialized* to the sum, then you can use a trigger.  That would be strange, though, because I would expect the order to be created before the `sub_order`s.

If you want to maintain the order amount as `sub_order`s are created, deleted, and updated, then you need triggers.  Or, just calculate the values on the fly.